# How can I remove a column from a pandas groupby if there are duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I run a `df.groupby(['join', 'churn']).count()` and it returns this:

```
join     churn  
2016-05  2016-05      1
         2016-06      5
         2017-07      2
         2018-08      1
2016-06  2016-06      2
         2016-07      9
         2016-11      1
         2017-06      2
```

How do I process this data further so it doesn't return a row when join == churn?

What I want:

```
join     churn  
2016-05  2016-06      5
         2017-07      2
         2018-08      1
2016-06  2016-07      9
         2016-11      1
         2017-06      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter before `groupby`

```
df.query('join!=churn').groupby(['join', 'churn']).count()
```

Comment: Just saw this. I'm not very familiar with df query. In terms of performance, how does it stack up against against a mask/filter like in my answer?

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 check https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html

Answer (score 0):

You can filter first:

```
mask = df['join'] != df['churn']
df[mask].groupby(['join', 'churn']).count()
```